# Unable to checkout wso2 samples

Tags: wso2, vcs-checkout

I am trying to checkout wso2 tutorials as mentioned at this link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0#ConfiguringSingleSign-OnwithSAML2.0-Prerequisites

Using the svn I am getting next error:

[image]

Could anyone please suggest the solution - how to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having a problem with your svn client.
You can either got URL from browser and download the content or use command line tool to download the content.

http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/5.0.0/modules/samples/sso/

```
wget -r --no-parent http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/5.0.0/modules/samples/sso/
```